# Animate element over a curve with element.animate()

Tags: javascript, web-animations

I need to animate translations of elements over paths such as the one shown below:

[image: De Casteljau's curve example]

Right now I am using a [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) callback that calculates the position on a [De Casteljau](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YATikPP2q70&noredirect=1) curve and then sets the element position via an inline CSS `translate3d()`.
This works, although it performs worse and is *very* verbose when compared to CSS animations.

[Web Animations](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36) seem like a good new option to animate elements when the destination is only known at runtime, but I cannot find anything to modify the animation between the start and end point.

**Is it possible to do the above using `element.animate()`**, or is it no more customisable than a CSS animation?

Comment: HTML5 offers a bezier function for canvas drawing but that probably is not suitable for you as you talk about moving elements (not just dots).

Answer (score 0):

With Web Animation API you could use `motion-path` property:

More information and live example here:

http://danielcwilson.com/blog/2015/09/animations-part-5/

https://codepen.io/danwilson/post/css-motion-paths

https://webdesigner-webdeveloper.com/weblog/exploring-web-animations/